# search and replace string from two lines

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I have file with

```
1111:22223322
0000440000
2222:77778866
0101550101
9999:87870087
7777556666
```

I need to replace in first line "33" with "44" from second line. Numbers is different but positions is same 5 and 6 after ":" replace with 5 and 6 from second line

Does anyone know a Unix command (or series of commands) to make this to all lines .Numbers from line2 replace line1 ...after that numbers from line4 replace line3 ... and then redirect them into a new file?

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the whole input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the odd numbered lines and then do the replacement when you reach the corresponding even numbered line, printing both lines before moving on to the next odd numbered line.

If you only want to print the lines that changed you can remove the `print source`.

```
$ cat a.awk
NR % 2 == 1 { target = $0 }
NR % 2 == 0 {
    source = $0;
    colon_pos = index(target, ":")
    new_target = substr(target, 1, colon_pos + 4) substr(source, 5, 2) substr(target, colon_pos + 7)
    print new_target
    print source
}

$ awk -f a.awk file > new_file

$ cat new_file
1111:22224422
0000440000
2222:77775566
0101550101
9999:87875587
7777556666
```

Comment: very good
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  val=index($0,":")
}
val!=0{
  line=$0
  prev_val=val
  next
}
{
  print substr(line,1,prev_val) substr(line,prev_val+1,4) substr($0,5,2) substr(line,prev_val+7) ORS $0
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: @Leva, could you please check this one too, if this helps you?